# In Unity how to save 3D model(prefab) to a PNG image with transparent background?

Tags: unity-game-engine

In Unity how to save 3D model(prefab) to a PNG image with transparent background?

If not possible in unity, how about using maya?

Comment: i am not sure what are you trying to do , but may this help to you 
https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/gui/uiobject3d-render-3d-models-on-any-unity-ui-canvas-92476

Answer (score 4):

There's no easy way but by searching I could come with this. Hope it what's you need.

[AssetPreview.GetAssetPreview](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetPreview.GetAssetPreview.html?_ga=2.43507685.1338121272.1581997971-1154459211.1559411979) to get a Texture2D of your model.

Then use [Texture2D.EncoreToPNG](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ImageConversion.EncodeToPNG.html) to encore it to a PNG.